# When are widgets deleted in Qt (QVBoxLayout class)?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I have some simple code to create a new widget using Qt:

```
Dock::Dock() : QDockWidget() {
    label = new QLabel(QLatin1String("TEST"));

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(label, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
    layout->addStretch(-1);

    QWidget* multiWidget = new QWidget();
    multiWidget->setLayout(layout);

    setWidget(multiWidget);
}
```

Where `label` is a private member `QLabel* label`.  My question is: am I responsible for deleting `label` in `Dock`'s destructor?

I tried changing the code so that `label` is a `std::shared_ptr<QLabel>`:

```
Dock::Dock() : QDockWidget() {
    label = std::make_shared<QLabel>(QLatin1String("TEST"));

    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    layout->addWidget(label.get(), 0, Qt::AlignTop);
    layout->addStretch(-1);

    QWidget* multiWidget = new QWidget();
    multiWidget->setLayout(layout);

    setWidget(multiWidget);
}
```

So that it is deleted automatically when `Dock' is destroyed but I get an error when I close the program.

Comment: In order to delete your label object you need to properly set its parent. In general it should be widget that holds it, i.e. `multiWidget` in your case.

Comment: @vahancho so when `mutliWidget` takes control of the layout does it also take control of the widgets in the layout? Is it deleting `label` for me?

Comment: Yes, `multiWidget` will delete its child object `label` if it's created before `label`. You might refer to this reading: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to properly set up the [objects tree](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) you need to do the following:

- Create the container widget first,
- Create child widget and set it's parent,
- Create layout of the container widget,
- Add widget to the layout.

Here is the code that demonstrates the mentioned approach:

```
Dock::Dock()
  :
    QDockWidget()
{
  QWidget* multiWidget = new QWidget;
  label = new QLabel(QLatin1String("TEST"), multiWidget); // Set parent

  QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(multiWidget); // Sets layout
  layout->addWidget(label, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
  layout->addStretch(-1);

  setWidget(multiWidget);
}
```

Comment: If you are going to use a layout it is not necessary to indicate a parent, since the layout will be established by your parent `label = new QLabel(QLatin1String("TEST"));`